# CGBitmapContextCreateImage or CGContextDrawImage doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, cgcontext, cgimageref

I can't solve this problem. Load image, convert to `CGImageRef`. Try to get bitmap context and render on the screen.

```
 NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringIMG];

   CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);
   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);

    NSInteger bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
    NSInteger bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);
    NSInteger bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef);
    NSInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

    size_t rawData = bytesPerRow*height;
    unsigned char *data = malloc(rawData);
    memset(data2, 0, rawData);

     CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo);


    CGImageRef imageRef2 = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

   // CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef2);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef2];//if i do like this i got white empty screen

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:result];
    [self.view addSubview:image];// if i do like this i got black rectangle on the white screen
```

I have no idea. I check by breakpoint that context is not null. I don't know what should i do. Please maybe anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you on main thread ?

Comment: I think so. I didn't do another one thread. how can i check it?

Comment: You should draw image, with a : CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image.CGImage); but, more simple, why don't you create it directly with imageRef instead of imageRef2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Category added it to UIImage for resizing using CoreGraphics

**UIImage+Resize.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Resizing)

-(UIImage*)resizedImageWithSize:(CGSize)size;

@end
```

**UIImage+Resizing.m**

```
#import "UIImage+Resizing.h"

@implementation UIImage (Resizing)

-(UIImage*)resizedImageWithSize:(CGSize)size {


    CGImageRef cgImage = [self CGImage];

    size_t bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(cgImage);

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, size.width, size.height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), cgImage);

    CGImageRef resizedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    UIImage *resizedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resizedImageRef];

    CFRelease(resizedImageRef);
    CFRelease(context);

    return resizedImage;

}

@end
```